# login com cpf ou e-mail em php

Tags: php, mysql, login

estou com um probleminha ao fazer um sistema de login que usuário deve poder se autenticar por seu e-mail ou cpf.

Estou fazendo a comparação com o valor do campo de login recebido, se for número eu faço pesquisa com cpf e se não for eu faço com e-mail. Veja abaixo:

```
 if (is_numeric($_POST['email_cpf'])) {
     //pesquisa com cpf
 }else{
     //pesquisa com e-mail
 }
```

Isso funciona, o problema é que quando o usuário coloca no campo login o cpf no formato com separadores 000.000.000-00, isso é dado como uma string e portanto faz pesquisa com o e-mail.

Fiz uma função para retirar os separadores, mas isso é ruim porque se o e-mail por exemplo tiver traços ou pontos, também serão removidos

Como faço para resolver isso?

Comment: Pode definir uma expressão regular que verifica se o valor condiz com um CPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de você verificar se o usuário digitou somente números, remova os pontos e traços utilizando a função [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) da seguinte forma:

```
$login = $_POST['email_cpf'];
$login = str_replace('.', '', $login);
$login = str_replace('-', '', $login);
```

Neste ponto você já terá o que o usuário digitou sem pontos ou traços na variável `$login`. Se na variável conter somente números você verifica pelo CPF,
caso contrário, você pega o que o usuário digitou inicialmente e verifica o e-mail:

```
if (is_numeric($login)) {
    //pesquisa com cpf
}else{
    $login = $_POST['email_cpf'];
    //pesquisa com e-mail
}
```

Você também pode fazer isso tudo de uma forma mais simplificada:

```
if (is_numeric(str_replace(array('.', '-'), $_POST['email_cpf']))) {
    //pesquisa com cpf
}else{
    //pesquisa com e-mail
}
```

Comment: Eu já tentei isso, mas o problema é que caso o usuário entrar com e-mail ao invés de cpf, e o e-mail tiver traços ou pontos, também serão removidos e portanto não daria certo.

Comment: Editei minha resposta, dê uma olhada...

Comment: A remoção deve valer apenas para a verificação junto ao `is_numeric`, mas o valor original deve permanecer inalterado.

Comment: Mas o que o usuário digitou esta da mesma forma na variável `$_POST['email_cpf']`. Só alteramos a variável `$login`.
De qualquer forma, adicionei uma forma simplificada de fazer isso tudo.
Dê uma olhada.

Comment: @Roberto, a função `str_replace` aceita um *array* como parâmetro, então você pode fazer tudo em apenas uma chamada.

Comment: Dessa eu não sabia, de qualquer forma fiz a alteração.
Vlw @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 1):

Com expressão regular, você pode fazer algo como:

```
if (preg_match("/^\d{3}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{3}-?\d{2}$/", $valor)) {
    // É CPF
} else {
    // É e-mail
}
```

Assim, os caracteres separadores ficarão opcionais, podendo tanto informar o CPF com apenas números ou com os separadores, desde que possua os 11 dígitos.

Com os caracteres `^` e `$` é definido o início e fim da expressão, garantindo que não haja nada a mais que o CPF no valor. Já o `\d{x}` cria grupos de `x` dígitos.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/zjDhYZ).

Comment: obrigado, mas achei melhor a solução do roberto, pois o usuário pode as vezes digitar um ponto a mais ou colocar o traço no lugar errado e etc.. E com o preg_match qualquer um desses pequenos errors vai cair na validação com email, e do jeito que o roberto fez não. E tem um error nessa regex sua ai, mas mesmo assim obrigado